# Reducing multiple variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby, reduce, enumerable

AFAIK when reducing an array we can only output once variable at the end like so:

```
(0..10).reduce(0) do |sum, value|
  sum + value
end
```

What if I have an array of hash objects, can I reduce the array and output multiple variables something like:

```
({:grade => 100, :sex => 'female'}, {:grade => 90, :sex => 'male'}).reduce(0, 0, 0) do |sum_of_grades, sum_of_male, sum_of_female, value|
  sum_of_grades = sum_of_grades + value[:grade]
  sum_of_male += 1 if value[:sex] == 'male'
  sum_of_female +=1 if value[:sex] == 'female
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aggregate multiple results in a hash or any other suitable object:

```
a.reduce({:sum_of_grades => 0, :sum_of_male => 0, :sum_of_female => 0}) do |result, value|
     result[:sum_of_grades] += value[:grade]
     result[:sum_of_male] += 1 if value[:sex] == 'male'
     result[:sum_of_female] += 1 if value[:sex] == 'female'
     result
end
```

Comment: You could also switch to `each_with_object` and not have to worry about the block's return value (but you'd have to switch the block's argument order).

Comment: @muistooshort I really don't understand why the argument order is different between the two methods, seems really silly. I confuse the two all the time.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Tell me about it. AFAIK the `reduce` order is standard for injecting/reducing, `each_with_object` matches `each_with_index`. On the upside, the order for `each_with_X` does happen to match the name (which I actually just noticed for the first time).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall @muistooshort I tend to do something like `a.map{|e| e.fetch(:grade)}.inject(:+)`, ie keeping the mapping and the reducing separate. Note that my snippet will return `nil` if there's no elements in `a`.